# How to change Magento's default date in calendar?

Tags: magento-1.8, product, date

My requirement is when I click on the frames of the calendar popup the text-box is filled up with the current date.

How I disable this. I want the date to be selected only when clicking respective dates and not the other parts.

Comment: can you put a screenshot of what you have and what you need? I'm not sure this is clear enough.

Comment: Hai Marius,

pleae check the link to view the screenshot
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vQa2s.png

When i click and drag the calendar the also the current date is selected into the textbox.So how to remove this feature from calender.Help any one ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting for the calendar. It is called `hiliteToday`.
If you change in `js/calendar/calendar.js`:

```
this.hiliteToday = true;
```

to

```
this.hiliteToday = false;
```

'today' will not be selected by default.
Of course it is not ok to edit the code files, but I don't know yet how you can change that setting without touching the core. There is always the option of cloning the file, modify the cloned file and include your cloned file in the design, but I'm sure there is a cleaner way.
I will post when I find one.
This should be enough to get you started.